# Converting ECI coordinate system to ECEF coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, c++

I have start and end date/time of TLE from satellite and so a matrix of ECI coordinate (122*4).

Generally, i want convert from ECI to LLA, and i know that first step is convert from ECI to ECEF, and then convert from ECEF to LLA. I implement convert from ECEF to LLA in C++.

In Matlab, there is a function to convert from ECI to LLA: `eci2lla()`.

How to convert from ECI to ECEF with this date/time in C++?

Comment: I use only start date/time, in first step, calculate Julian Day from start date/time. Now, must calculate DCM (Direcrt Cosine Matrix) from ECI. in MATLAB, we can use dcmeci2ecef, But i will calculate this DCM in C++. How to calculate DCM in c++?